# How to keep data in activity from database

Tags: java, android, database

I have this app where I succeed sending intent from Log In Activity and receiving intent for User Activity (See attachment), but when I navigate from other pages and then returning to my UserAcitivy ie; Home, Contact Us it results "Null Values", I want to keep the data in User Activity even I navigate from other pages. Help please. Thank you!

[Successful store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVZgO.jpg)

[Null values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJYzX.png)

Here's my codes..

public class LoginActivityEN extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
private static final String URL_FOR_LOGIN = "http://192.168.13.40/android_login_example/login.php";
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private EditText loginInputUsername, loginInputPassword;
Button btnlogin;
Button btnLinkSignup;


// Session Manager Class
SessionManager session;

//Storing Sessions
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_en);




    // Session Manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("user_id", "password");


    //Bottom Navigation
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavView_Bar);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
        Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(1);
        menuItem.setChecked(true);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){

                    case R.id.navigation_home:
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(LoginActivityEN.this, Home.class);
                        startActivity(intent1);
                        break;

                    case R.id.navigation_card:



                        break;

                    case R.id.navigation_price:
                        Intent intent3 = new Intent(LoginActivityEN.this, PriceActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent3);
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_more:
                        Intent intent4 = new Intent(LoginActivityEN.this, More.class);
                        startActivity(intent4);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


        //Login Activity
        loginInputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_input_username);
        loginInputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_input_password);
        btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btnLinkSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerbutton);
        // Progress dialog
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                loginUser(loginInputUsername.getText().toString(),
                        loginInputPassword.getText().toString());

            }
        });
        //Register
        btnLinkSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterEN.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

private void loginUser( final String username, final String password) {


    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String cancel_req_tag = "login";
    progressDialog.setMessage("Logging you in...");
    showDialog();
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URL_FOR_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();
            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                if (!error) {
                    String user = jObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("customers_firstname");
                    String user1 = jObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("customers_lastname");
                    String user2 = jObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("reward_points");
                    String user3 = jObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("NoShares");
                    String user4 = jObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("CardType_ID");
                    String user5 = jObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("Card_No");
                    // Launch User activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivityEN.this, UserActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("customers_firstname", user);
                    intent.putExtra("customers_lastname", user1);
                    intent.putExtra("reward_points", user2);
                    intent.putExtra("NoShares", user3);
                    intent.putExtra("CardType_ID", user4);
                    intent.putExtra("Card_No", user5);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                    if(username.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0){
                        session.createLoginSession("username", "password");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Session Active", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                } else {

                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("username", username);
            params.put("customers_password", password);
            return params;
        }

    };
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppSingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(strReq,cancel_req_tag);
}

private void showDialog() {
    if (!progressDialog.isShowing())
        progressDialog.show();
}
private void hideDialog() {
    if (progressDialog.isShowing())
        progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

UserActivity.java

public class UserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private TextView greetingTextView;
private TextView totpoints;
private TextView totshare;
private Button btnLogOut;
private ImageView cardshow;
private ImageView bmbc;
private TextView bmbc_text;

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;


// Session Manager Class
SessionManager session;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);



    // Session class instance
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());



    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavView_Bar);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
    Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(1);
    menuItem.setChecked(true);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(UserActivity.this, Home.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                    break;

                case R.id.navigation_card:

                    break;

                case R.id.navigation_price:
                    Intent intent3 = new Intent(UserActivity.this, PriceActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent3);
                    break;

                case R.id.navigation_more:
                    Intent intent4 = new Intent(UserActivity.this, PriceActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent4);
                    break;
            }


            return false;
        }


    });



    greetingTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.greeting_text_view);
    totpoints = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.au_tpresult);
    totshare = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.au_tsresult);
    btnLogOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout_button);
    cardshow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card_stack);



    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String user = intent.getStringExtra("customers_firstname");
    String user1 = intent.getStringExtra("customers_lastname");
    String user2 = intent.getStringExtra("reward_points");
    String user3 = intent.getStringExtra("NoShares");
    String user4 = intent.getStringExtra("CardType_ID");
    String user5 = intent.getStringExtra("Card_No");


    greetingTextView.setText(user  + " " +  user1);
    totpoints.setText(user2);
    totshare.setText(user3);


    if (user4 == (null)) {
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card_stack)).setImageResource(R.color.transparent);
    } else if (user4.equals("0")) {
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card_stack)).setImageResource(R.drawable.thar_silver);
    } else if (user4.equals("1")) {
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card_stack)).setImageResource(R.drawable.thar_gold);

    }

    // Progress dialog
    btnLogOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            session.logoutUser();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Session Ended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivityEN.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    session.checkLogin();

    //CARD NUMB
```

Comment: Hi in that case store all the data in shared preference and access where ever you want.After successful login instead of passing through intent store in shared preference , then retrieve in home page.

Comment: You can accomplish your task with what @Shanmugam said or you can save those variable values in onsaveinstancestate and restore them on your on create method. Make sure that the views you want to resore are fields of class not local variables of some method. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches you could use.

1. Persistance storage(Long Duration, Even after app closes) :
   a. use SharedPreferences, b. use Sqlite
2. Other way is .to Extend the Application class and Store it in a variable, it remains until app is closed.(Short Duration, During a app session and closing of app)

Your approach depends upon ur data lifespan

Comment: Best option is Shared Preferences but I am referring to a Non-Static data.